# Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role,could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: javascript, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc, eager

I have this error when using ***FetchType.LAZY***

> Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of
>   role: com.websystique.springmvc.model.User.userProfiles, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session

Here is my model class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="APP_USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="SSO_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String ssoId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="PASSWORD", nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APP_USER_USER_PROFILE", 
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, 
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") })
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();

    getters/setters ....
```

And this is my javascript ajax:

```
/* Populate DataTable of list of all User existed using ajax */
function populateUserDataTable() {
    $("#dataTables-example").dataTable().fnDestroy();

    /* set class and onClick event listener */
    var buttonEditClass = 'class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"';
    buttonEditClass += 'data-target="#modalAddCargoUser"';
    buttonEditClass += 'onClick="searchCargoDetailViaAjax(this)"';

    var buttonDeleteClass = 'class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"';
    buttonDeleteClass += 'data-target="#modalDeleteCargoUser"';
    buttonDeleteClass += 'onClick="fetchDeleteId(this)"'

    $
            .ajax({
                'url' : '' + myContext + '/ajaxUserList',
                'method' : "GET",
                'contentType' : 'application/json'
            })
            .done(
                    function(data) {
                        var dataToString = JSON.stringify(data);
                        $('#dataTables-example')
                                .dataTable(
                                        {
                                            responsive : true,
                                            "aaData" : data,
                                            "columns" : [
                                                    {
                                                        "data" : "firstName"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "data" : "lastName"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "data" : "email"
                                                    },

                                                    {
                                                        "data" : "ssoId"
                                                    },

                                                    {

                                                        /*
                                                         * Add button to
                                                         * dataTable
                                                         */
                                                        sortable : false,
                                                        "render" : function(
                                                                data, type,
                                                                full, meta) {
                                                            var buttonID = full.ssoId;
                                                            var drawActionButton = ' <button id='
                                                                    + buttonID
                                                                    + ' '
                                                                    + buttonEditClass
                                                                    + ' >Edit</button> ';
                                                            drawActionButton += ' <button id='
                                                                    + buttonID
                                                                    + ' '
                                                                    + buttonDeleteClass
                                                                    + ' >Delete</button> ';
                                                            return drawActionButton;
                                                        }
                                                    } ]
                                        })
                    });
}
```

My controller class:

```
/*
     * This method will redirect user page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/ajaxUserList" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> ajaxUserList(ModelMap model) {
        /* Populate DataTable */
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return users;
    }
```

my Service class:

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDao dao;

    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return dao.findAllUsers();
    }


}
```

But when i change the the ***FetchType.EAGER*** it works fine. I also tried to read the difference between the EAGER and LAZY and i think in my case i prefer to use LAZY due to its more less memory usage etc.

Is there other way how to make my ajax work using LAZY? Any help is extremely appreciated.

=========================================================================
**UPDATE**

Here is my UserDaoImpl class:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, User> implements UserDao {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

    public User findById(int id) {
        User user = getByKey(id);
        if(user!=null){
            Hibernate.initialize(user.getUserProfiles());
        }
        return user;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria().addOrder(Order.asc("firstName"));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);//To avoid duplicates.
        List<User> users = (List<User>) criteria.list();

        // No need to fetch userProfiles since we are not showing them on list page. Let them lazy load. 
    // Uncomment below lines for eagerly fetching of userProfiles if you want.

    /*for(User user : users){
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getUserProfiles());
    }*/

        return users;
    }   

}
```

AbstractDao class:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    public void update(T entity){
        getSession().update(entity);
    }

    protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }



}
```

@ Bushra Hannure thank you, i accidentally bump the code in Dao i enable the

> for(User user : users){
>             Hibernate.initialize(user.getUserProfiles());       }

then change the FetchType to LAZY again and i can use my ajax call without a problem. sorry for my noob question.

But i cant undertand how did it override the method. it says the fetching will be EAGERLY but i cant totally understand. but somehow it works even now even the model class set it into LAZY.

as for reference of this code here is the link: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/

Comment: please add your DAO class

Answer (score 0):

Your application configuration does not allow Hibernate session in the view. Session is closing after request is done and before rendering the view.

FetchType.EAGER loads all data on the request BEFORE rendering the view and application work fine. FetchType.LAZY loads data on demand - here in the view so you get the Hibernate exception because session is closed at this moment.

For example for Spring Boot configuration is:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view: true
```